# Javah missing after JDK install (Linux)

Tags: android, linux, javah

I'm trying to setup Android development with Eclipse (Indigo), on Fedora17.
Almost everything seems to work, just the javah is missing, to build the C headers with, for native (NDK / JNI) modules.

On my windows install of the tool chain it was in the same folder javac was in, but this is not the case on the Linux machine.

I previously installed Oracle's JDK1.7, found out that it's to new for something else I wanted to do (but also there, no javah), uninstalled it, now JDK1.6 is installed.

What might be wrong?

Comment: I don't think java is missing. Type in terminal `java` and `javac` to verify whether the runtime environment and the compiler is missing or not.

Comment: No, java and javac are present, but javah is missing.

Comment: Ah sorry, just notices that the original post said "java is missing", corrected that, I meant javah missing - now it's the headline, too?? I'm 100% positive I wrote javah there, was that auto-"corrected" ?

Comment: Edited the main post again - please leave the head line intact, it's *javah* that's missing, not java !

Comment: did you try to `locate` or `find` it?

Comment: I tried find, it does exist, in /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin, while, when I call 'whereis javac', or java, for that matter, I am pointed to /usr/bin/, where javah is not.

Is it supposed to be that way? If not, what should I do?

Comment: (the question may sound stupid, but I'm a Linux n00b and afraid to do wild things and do damage ;-) )

Comment: @user1847129 How did u install your java ? what is the output of the `locate javah` command ?

Comment: locate found nothing IIRC (not on the machine here).
Jdk1.7 I had installed via rpm <packagename.rpm>, since that version was downloadable as such.
Later, I installed jdk1.6 with sh <packagename.rpm.bin>
And did all that alternatives jazz, as described here: [link](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)
When jdk1.6 didn't install where the jdk1.6 version of that tutorial told it would and thus the alternatives stuff didn't work, I uninstalled everything and just installed jdk1.6

Answer (score 3):

This tool has been removed from the JDK

https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/313

Answer (score 1):

In linux machines, JavaH is normally located in `/usr/bin/javah`.

If you try to find this file with `locate`, it is normally a good idea to run before `updatedb`, since the database is not updated unless this command is run either by the user or a cron job. You could try finding the file with `find / |grep javah`

P.S. Sorry to post this as an asnwer. I suppose the corret way to go would have been a comment, but still don't have enough reputation to post a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try `gjavah` rather than `javah`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `javah` link is not created during JDK install. You have to create it manually:

Check where is installed `java`:

```
$ ls -l `which java`
lrwxrwxrwx root root 26 15 juil. 02:05 /usr/bin/java -> /usr/java/default/bin/java
```

Create the symlink in the same directory:

```
$ su
# cd /usr/bin
# ln -s /usr/java/default/bin/javah
```