# How to set `Java headers gen.:` for R (to install `rJava`)

Tags: java, r, archlinux, rjava

I am trying to install the package `rJava` in R on Arch Linux.

I got the error:

```
configure: error: One or more Java configuration variables are not set.
Make sure R is configured with full Java support (including JDK). Run
R CMD javareconf as root to add Java support to R.
```

Running `sudo R CMD javareconf`, I can see that `Java headers gen.:` is not set, but I have failed to figure out how to set it.

Here is the full java configuration seen by R (beside `Java haders gen.`, the rest looks ok to me):

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 10
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: 
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
```

I do have `javah` in `/usr/bin`. But how do I "tell" this to R?

Comment: Can you go to usr/bin and check whether javah is present?

Comment: I have a symlink: `javah -> /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/javah`

Comment: Oh! Your comment pushed me to follow the symlink (and a 2nd symlink in the path) and to find out that there is no `javah` in `/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin/`. So I guess that's why R can't find it... When I was looking for `javah` with `locate` to make sure it existed, I was getting the symlink as a result. So I thought that it was fine and failed to see that it lead nowhere. Now... I am not sure where to find `javah`...

Comment: (Thank you @IvoVidovic for pointing me to the right direction).

Comment: Now... where do I find `javah`? [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526701/javah-missing-after-jdk-install-linux) did not help me. And the only `javah` I seem to have on my machine is that symlink leading to a non existent file.

Comment: On my machine it is in the same package as javac and since you have javac you have installed a jdk, so I don't know, maybe try reinstalling your jdk?

Comment: Apparently, `javah` is missing from the arch linux openjdk 10 ([the file is not listed in the package contents](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/jdk10-openjdk/))... I guess I will try to install another openjdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @IvoVidovic's comment, I went to `/usr/bin` and inspected `javah`. It turned out that it was a symlink to a non-existent file. In fact, `javah` is missing from Arch Linux OpenJDK 10 (the file is not listed in the [package contents](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/jdk10-openjdk/)).

- Installing `OpenJDK 9`,
- updating my `JAVA_HOME` with `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk`,
- setting OpenJDK 9 as my default jdk with `sudo archlinux-java set java-9-openjdk`,
- and re-running `sudo R CMD javareconf` allowed R to find all the java files, including `javah`.

I now have:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 9.0.4
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
```

and I could install `rJava` without any issue.

Thanks again to @IvoVidovic who sent me in the right direction with his comment.